# jQuery Dynamic Table Not Returning Data Changes

Tags: jquery, arrays, dynamic-tables

I have a table that is dynamically created with array data passed into a function. This data set to rows and then appended to the tbody. This all works great.

The table also includes, check boxes, a text input and a drop down menu within each row.

If the user makes any changes and clicks the save button, the changes are not reflected in the rows when the data is retrieved. It is important that each row does not save on change of input and only save one, all or none after the user has made all changes.

```
<div>
    <table id="myTable" class="sortable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Rank</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Priority</th>
                <th>Completed</th>
                <th>Approved</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="button" value="Save Changes" id="btnSaveTable" />
</div>


function PopulateTable(myObjectArray){

    var tableRows = [];
    var tableRow;
    $.each(myObjectArray, function(n){

        var completedSelected = "";
        var approvedSelected = "";
        if(myObjectArray[n].Completed == true){completedSelected = "checked";};
        if(myObjectArray[n].Approved == true){approvedSelected = "checked";};

        //THE FOLLOWING IS HARD CODED BECAUSE THERE ARE NO OTHER OPTIONS.
        var pdo = [
        { "value":"0", "name":"" },
        { "value":"1", "name":"1" },
        { "value":"2", "name":"3" },
        { "value":"3", "name":"3" },
        ]

        //pdo = 'PRIORITY DISPLAY OBJECT". GOING THROUGH AND SETTING 'SELECTED'
        //ON THE CHOICE BEFORE CREATING TABLE, OTHERWISE WILL NOT WORK.
        $.each(pdo, function(t){
            if(pdo[t].value == myObjectArray[n].Priority){
                pdo.value = myObjectArray[n].Priority + ' "selected"';
            };
        });

        tableRow = "<tr>" +
        "<td class='hidden'>" + myObjectArray[n].Id + "</td>" + 

        "<td class='center'><input class='tbRankNumber' type='text' maxlength='3' value='" + myObjectArray[n].Rank + "'/></td>" + 

        "<td>" + myObjectArray[n].LastName + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + myObjectArray[n].FirstName + "</td>" +

        "<td class='center'><select id='ddPriority'><option selected value='" +  myObjectArray[n].Priority + "'>" + myObjectArray[n].Priority + "</option><option value='0'></option><option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option><option value = '3'>3</option></select></td>" +

        "<td class='center'><input type='checkbox'" +  completedSelected + "/></td>" +
        "<td class='center'><input type='checkbox'" +  approvedSelected + " class='cbVerified'/></td>" +
        "</tr>"

        tableRows.push(tableRow);
    });

    var myTableData = tableRows.toString();
    $('#myTable tbody').append(myTableData);
};

$('#btnSaveTable').click(function (){

    var rows = $("tbody tr",$("#myTable")).map(function() { 
        return [$("td",this).map(function() { 
            return this.innerHTML;     
        }).get()];
    }).get();

    $.each(rows, function(i, row){
        //COLUMNS: 0 = ID, 1 = Rank, 4 = Priority, 5 = Completed, 6 = Approved 
        //GET VALUE OF VALUE IN Rank COLUMN. A '+7' IS NEEDED TO COMPENSATE FOR 'VALUE="'
        var idxRankVal = row[1].search("value") + 7;
        var rankVal = row[1].charAt(idxRankVal);
        //SIMILAR TO Rank
        var idxPriority = row[4].search("selected") - 3;
        var PriorityVal = row[4].charAt(idxPriority);
        //CHECKBOXES ARE DIFFERENT. A '-1' WILL MEAN 'NO' OR 'FALSE'. ANY OTHER NUMBER IS THE OPPOSITE.
        var idxCompleted = row[5].search("checked");
        var idxApproved = row[6].search("checked");

        //!!!!!!!NOT GETTING CHANGES MADE IN TABLE. MAYBE DO ONCHANGE EVENTS TO SET THE VALUE?!!!!!!!!

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just used datatables.js. Works perfectly . It is free and even does more than I need it too.